# Why does 'if type(x) not list' return an error?

Tags: python

I would like to use `if type(x) not list`
instead of `if not isinstance(x, list)`
Am I missing something?

`if not isinstance(x, list)` seems excessive
since I'm not checking for class inheritance.

Comment: `isinstance` is never excessive unless you have a good reason *not* to check for inheritance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the `is`:

```
if type(x) is not list:
```

but `if not isinstance(x, list)` is not excessive, really. You should always allow for subclasses, it'll make your life easier at some point. Why close the door on that option?